# How to present a modal view from the centre of the view clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a list of movies in the collection view cells. When a collection view cell is clicked an info modal displays the information of the movie. I would like to present the info view from the centre of the collection view cell clicked [Like the modal view scales out of the collection view cell].

I tried using UIView.animate functions to achieve this but it is not happening right.

```
infoView.bringOut(from: selectedCollectionViewCell)

extension UIView {
    func bringOut(from sender: UIView?) {
        guard let sender = sender else { return }
        self.center = sender.center
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 7,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear,
                       animations: {
                        self.center = baseView.centre
                        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                       },completion: nil)
    }
}
```

baseView is the view upon which my entire app rests. I expected the view to scale from the collection view cell to the baseView.centre, but the view always scales from the top left corner of the baseView to the centre of the baseView.

Answer (score 0):

The `collection view cell` and the `infoView` have two different coordinat systems, for that reason it doesn't work. You should try to use the `convert` function to convert the cell center into the baseView cooordinate system.

Link documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert